# how to return 2 values from one function

Tags: c#

i have a function that calculate two locations and i want to get them both, is there a way to get two values returned from the same function, with out turning them into an array. i think something with an out argument or something like that... tnx. here my code:

```
public static int Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{
  int  XLocation = p_2 - p_1;
  int YLocation = p_4-p_3;
  return XLocation,YLocation;
}

public void Print()
{
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are multiple ways for that:

1) Use:

```
public KeyValuePair<int, int> Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{                 
    return new KeyValuePair<int,int>(p_2 - p_1, p_4-p_3);
}
```

or

```
static Tuple<int, int> Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{
    return new Tuple<int, int>(p_2 - p_1, p_4-p_3);
}
```

2) Use custom class like `Point`

```
public class Point
{
    public int XLocation { get; set; }
    public int YLocation { get; set; }
}

public static Point Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4) 
{    
     return new Point 
     {
        XLocation  = p_2 - p_1;
        YLocation = p_4 - p_3;
     }      
 }
```

3) Use `out` keyword:

```
   public static int Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4, out int XLocation, out int YLocation)
   {
        XLocation = p_2 - p_1;    
        YLocation = p_4 - p_3;
   }
```

Here is comparison of these methods: [multiple-return-values](http://www.dotnetperls.com/multiple-return-values).

**The fastest way (best performance)  is:**

```
public KeyValuePair<int, int> Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{                 
    return new KeyValuePair<int,int>(p_2 - p_1, p_4-p_3);
}
```

Comment: Should be :      return new Point() 
     {
        XLocation  = p_2 - p_1,
        YLocation = p_4 - p_3
     };

Comment: @algreat You are really great <3 :) Superbly Explained

Answer (score 13):

Use a struct or a class:

```
public struct Coordinates
{
    public readonly int x;
    public readonly int y;

    public Coordinates (int _x, int _y) 
    {
        x = _x;
        y = _y;
    }
}

public static Coordinates Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4) 
{
    return new Coordinates(p_2 - p_1, p_4 - p_3);
}
```

I find it prettier than using the `out` keyword.

Comment: Mutable value types are evil.

Comment: For this concrete return value i would take the [`Point` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx).

Comment: I would too. A pity Microsoft made Point mutable. :)

Comment: Made the struct immutable - if there are any errors please let me know. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can't return 2 values this way. But you can pass variables as out variables, like this :

```
  public static void Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4, out int XLocation, out int YLocation)
{
    XLocation = p_2 - p_1;

    YLocation = p_4-p_3;
}
```

Then you just have to pass the destination variables to the method :

```
int Xlocation, YLocation;
Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4, out int XLocation, out int YLocation);
```

and it will fill them with the computed values.

Comment: it keeps asking me for a return value... return what?

Comment: @darko: your method should return void. Can you check ?

Answer (score 6):

As of C# 7.0 you can use Tuples like this:

```
(string, string) LookupName(long id) // tuple return type
{
    ... // retrieve first, middle and last from data storage
    return (first, last); // tuple literal
}

var names = LookupName(id);
WriteLine($"found {names.Item1} {names.Item2}.");
```

or even with names:

```
(string first, string middle, string last) LookupName(long id)

var names = LookupName(id);
WriteLine($"found {names.first} {names.last}.");
```

> Further information can be found [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/).

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible return two values by operator 'return'.
You may use following code with 'struct':

```
public static Position Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{

Position location;
location.xLocation = p_2 - p_1;
location.yLocation =p_4-p_3;;

return location;
}

public struct Position
{
public int xLocation;
public int yLocation;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an out, a Coordinate struct or a Tuple.

With a tuple:

```
public Tuple<int, int> GetLocation()
{
     return new Tuple<int,int>(1,2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are employing windows forms, you may use `Point` struct;

```
public static Point Location(Point p1, Point p2)
{
    return new Point(p2.X - p1.X, p2.Y - p1.Y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case, when method isn't a part of public contract, I prefer using of [tuples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx):

```
private Tuple<int, string> Foo()
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `Tuple<T1, T2>` or use out parameters.

Answer (score 0):

**use array list**

```
public ArrayList Location(int p_1, int p_2, int p_3, int p_4)
{
 ArrayList ar = new ArrayList();
 ar.AddRange(new string[] { "", "" });  
 int  XLocation = p_2 - p_1;
 int YLocation = p_4-p_3;
 ar[0] = XLocation.ToString(); 
 ar[1] = YLocation.ToString(); 
 return ar;
 }
```

Comment: This is by far the most inefficient answer.